# React JS / Apollo Client - How to cancel/stop a useLazyQuery when user leave component?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using useLazyQuery function and I don't know how to cancel/stop the request when user leave the component.

This is my code:

```
  const [getPosts] = useLazyQuery(GET_POSTS);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    fetchPosts();

    return () => {
      // Leave component: How stop the request
      
    }

  }, []);
```

Thank
Best Regard

Comment: This might help https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/8858.

Answer (score 3):

You can use abort controller, something like this...

```
  const abortController = useRef(new abortController());
  const [fetchPosts] = useLazyQuery(GET_POSTS,{
      context: {
        fetchOptions: {
          signal: abortController.current.signal,
        },
      },
    });
  const abort = () => {
    abortController.current.abort()
    abortController.current = new abortController() 
    /** 
     * setting the ref to a new abortController allows the signal 
     * to be reset for the next time. Considering you are doing 
     * this on component unmount, you shouldn't need to do it, 
     * but if you wanted to cancel requests multiple times without
     * un-mounting this would be necessary.
     */

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
    return () => {
      // Leave component: How stop the request
      abort()
    }
  }, []);
```

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9583

Comment: Typo, it's `AbortController` and not `abortController`